# Can't pass authenticated user details to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I am having issues passing user details after authenticating the user. The variable `$newUser` has the required information, but it can't be passed to the `user.index` view. I am using Laravel 5.1.

```
Route::get('user/home', ['as' => 'home', function () {
    return view('user.index');
}]);

Route::get('{provider}/login', function ($provider) {
   global $newUser;
   OAuth::login($provider, function ($user, $userdetails) {
       $newUser = $userdetails;
       $email = DB::table('users')->where('email', $newUser->email)->value('email');

    if( isset($email)) {
        echo "Welcome " . $newUser->full_name . " <br/>";
    }
    else {
        echo "New User! <br/>";
        $user->name = $newUser->full_name;
        $user->email = $newUser->email;
        $user->save();
    }
  });

    $newUser = (array) $newUser;

    return view('user.index', $newUser);
});
```

Comment: This `return view('user.index', $newUser);` doesn't pass anything. It should be `return view('user.index', ['newUser' => $newUser']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
view('user.index', compact('newUser'));
```

Comment: The reason this will work is because it creates an array of the format `['newUser' => $newUser]`. Otherwise, the view's data *is* the `$newUser` object, unnested. So the data scope is in the `$newUser` object, rather than a container for it where you access it via a key

Comment: Please [edit] with more information (such as @Josh's comment). Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Well just wondering, why don't you use a controller and make your code more explicit so that coming back to your coding 6 months from now would be easy for you to understand.
Anyway, if your using the Auth facade, you should be able to use

```
Auth::user()
```

inside your view to retrieve it or try seeing the available method of the OAuth class. Or if you want to keep your code as it is try

```
return view('user.index', compact('newUser'));
```